# Compact Normal Operators and orthogonal projection

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I am trying to solve this question in analysis course which was asked in my assignment.

Question: Let H be a Hilbert Space and let $T\in L(H)$ be compact normal operator. We denote by $\sigma_{P}(T)$ the set of eigenvalues of T. If $\lambda \in \sigma_{P} (T)$ , we denote by $P_{\lambda}$ , the orthonormal projection of $Ker (T- \lambda I)$ . Show that for $y\in H$ , the following properties are equivalent:

(1) The equation Tx=y has atleast 1 solution.

(2) $\sum_{\lambda \in \sigma_{P}(T) /{0} }$ $\frac{1} { |\lambda|^2 } ||P_{\lambda} x||^2 <\infty$.

Thoughts: If (2) holds I have showed (1) but for converse I am not able to make any progress.

Can you please help?

Comment: It might be a good idea to show us (in your question) how you proved (2) implies (1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a misprint in $(2)$: $x$ should be replaced by $y.$ The operator $T$ can be represented by $$T=\sum_{\lambda\in\sigma_p(T)\setminus\{0\}}\lambda P_\lambda$$ where the series is convergent with respect to the operator norm. The equation $Tx=y$ takes the form $$y=Tx=\sum_{\lambda\in\sigma_p(T)\setminus\{0\}}\lambda P_\lambda x$$ Hence $P_0y=0,$ where $P_0$ is the orthogonal projection onto $\ker T,$ and $$P_\lambda y=\lambda P_\lambda x\quad \lambda\in\sigma_p(T)\setminus\{0\}$$ Therefore $$\|x\|^2=\|P_0x\|^2+\sum_{\lambda\in\sigma_p(T)\setminus\{0\}}\|P_\lambda x\|^2 \ge \sum_{\lambda\in\sigma_p(T)\setminus\{0\}}{1\over |\lambda|^{2}}\|P_\lambda y\|^2$$ Thus the conditions $(2)$ and $P_0y=0$ are necessary for solvability of the equation $Tx=y.$ On the other hand if $(2)$ holds and $P_0y=0$ then $$x:=\sum_{\lambda\in\sigma_p(T)\setminus\{0\}}{1\over \lambda }\,P_\lambda y$$ provides a solution of $Tx=y$

Comment: How does $P_0 y=0$ and how does $P_{\lambda} y \neq\lambda {P_{\lambda}}^2 x$?

Comment: We have $P_\lambda P_\mu=0$ for $\lambda\neq \mu.$ Look at the formula for $y.$ Only $\lambda\neq 0$ show up in the sum. Hence $P_0y=0.$ Similarly for a fixed $\lambda_0$ we have $P_{\lambda_0}y= \lambda_0 P_{\lambda_0}x.$